# Remove entity and relations the correct way (JPA)

Tags: jpa, entity, dao

I have an entity Task and a dao for it: TaskDao. A Task entity has a ManyToOne mapping to Category. When I delete a Task, I also need to remove the Task from the collection in Category:

```
// remove() method in TaskDao
public void remove (Task p_task) {
    // p_task is Detached, p_task.getCategory() is Detached
    p_task = em.merge(p_task);
    // p_task is Attached, p_task.getCategory() is Attached
    em.remove(p_task);
    // p_task is Detached, p_task.getCategory() is Attached
    p_task.getCategory().removeTask(p_task);
}
```

The comments indicate (at that point) if the p_task and/or p_task.category are Attached/Detached. First let me explain why I choose this order of statements. First I need to merge the p_task, so that p_task.category gets attached and also in order to remove the p_task it need the be merged. The p_task is removed from the category collection at the end, because em.remove(p_task) can throw an ConstraintException, it that case the task should not be removed from the category collection.

Is this the right approah? Also, I was surprised that after em.remove(p_task), p_task.category is still attached.

**Edit:** I should give some code from the entity classes.

```
public class Task implements Serializable {

    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, optional = false)
    private Category category;

}

public class Category implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, mappedBy = "category")
    private List<Task> taskCollection;

    public void addTask (Task p_task) {
        if (taskCollection == null) {
            taskCollection = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        if (!taskCollection.contains(p_task)) {
            taskCollection.add(p_task);
        }
    }

    public void removeTask (Task p_task) {
        taskCollection.remove(p_task);
    }
}
```

In the following code the p_task is removed from category.taskCollection, while the transaction is rolled back:

```
// remove() method in TaskDao
public void remove (Task p_task) {
    p_task = em.merge(p_task);
    p_task.getCategory().removeTask(p_task); // will not be rolled back if em.remove(p_task) throws an exception
    em.remove(p_task);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's OK, AFAIK. You have some incorrect assumptions, though:

1. em.remove(p_task) will not throw a ConstraintException. The flush od the removal will do. If this exception is thrown, the only thing to do is to rollback the transaction and close the entity manager anyway, because it will leave it in an inconsistent state. So deleting the task before or after removing it from its category doesn't make much difference.
2. You remove a task, but don't remove tha category. So why wouldn't the category still be attached?

Comment: 1. But the p_task.getCategory().removeTask(p_task) statement will not be rolled back, right? That leaves an inconsistency between db and in-memory data.  
2. When I remove a task, I don't want the remove the associated category. I do want the deleted task out of category.taskCollection.

Comment: If you rollback the transaction, every modification done during the transaction is rolled back. If you close the session, every entity it holds in memory is detached and must be considered inconsistent. You must forget about them.

Comment: I use CMT, so I don't actually control the transactions myself. Would you recommend deleting the in-memory references before calling em.remove()?

Comment: No. What I say is that such an exception should cause the transaction to rollback (by just letting it walk up the call stack). I you get this exception since the transaction is rolled back, both th entity removal (from the DB) and its removal (from its category) will be rolled back, so the order of these two operations doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Its the right aproach. You have to remove the task from the set to ensure the sets functionality.

Maybe check if p_task is realy detached before merging it and if the tasks c